# Jenkins: Using XmlSlurper In Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, xmlslurper

Using XmlSlurper, I am trying to read an XML file (specifically Web.config from a .Net-based API) as part of a Jenkins pipeline.  I do not seem to be able to access any attributes of elements.  The error I get is:

```
No such field found: field groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild primary
```

Below is my attempt to break this down into the simplest case:

```
script {
    def xml = """
              <colors>
                  <color primary="true">Red</color>
                  <color primary="true">Yellow</color>
                  <color primary="true">Blue</color>
                  <color primary="false">Purple</color>
              </colors>                    
              """

    def colors = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    echo "First Color: ${colors.color[0]}" //works fine
    echo "First Color: ${colors.color[0]} Primary? ${colors.color[0].@primary}" //fails

}
```

I am using Jenkins 2.121.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Out of curiosity, all my research showed that the syntax I was using should be correct.  Do you know if something changed, or did I just miss a nuance of the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `${colors.color[0].@primary}` to `${colors.color[0]['@primary']}`

Answer (score 0):

**disable "Use groovy sandbox".**

The source of the problem is code via a Jenkinsfile, which I believe always runs in the sandbox.

Works fine, when its unchecked. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which also worked.  I chose the accepted answer simply because it avoids any security issues related to running outside the sandbox.